# When is the product of an infinite family of simplicial sets also a homotopy product?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories, derived-functors

The homotopy product of an infinite family of simplicial sets can be computed
by deriving the product functor sSet<sup>W</sup>→sSet, for example,
by performing the componentwise fibrant replacement using Kan's Ex<sup>∞</sup> functor
and then taking the ordinary product.

If the simplicial sets are already Kan, then their product is also their homotopy product.
There are families of simplicial sets for which this is false,
an example is given in the comments to the question [Commutation of simplicial homotopy colimits and homotopy products in spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181188/commutation-of-simplicial-homotopy-colimits-and-homotopy-products-in-spaces).

Is it possible to relax the Kan condition so that the ordinary
product still computes the homotopy product?
Are there any references for such questions?

For example, one potential relaxation that I have in mind is to require
that every horn H→X has a filling up to a homotopy, meaning that there
is a simplicial homotopy Δ¹×H→X that does not move any of the vertices of H
and whose bottom face is the given map H→X and the top face has a filling in the usual sense.

Comment: Here's a simple observation: let us say that a simplicial set $X$ has property $C_n$ if two vertices are in the same connected component of $X$ if and only if there is a path of length $\le n$ connecting them. So for example Kan complexes have property $C_1$. Then for every positive integer $n$,  $\pi_0$ preserves products of families of simplicial sets having property $C_n$. This seems to suggest that it suffices to satisfy the Kan condition up to some finite subdivision...